# Retornar Join Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

Estou tentando retornar um join para minha classe e ele está me dando o seguinte erro

> Erro  1   Não é possível converter implicitamente o tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' em
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' C:\Projetos_ASP.NET\AdvanceTechniques\Models\Repository\ProductRepository.cs    40  30  AdvanceTechniques

Segue o código abaixo.

```
public List<Line> Get()
{
    return context.
        Lines.
        Join(
            context.Products,
            lines => lines.ID,
            products => products.LineID,
            ((products, lines)
                => new { lines, products}
        )).
        OrderByDescending(products => products.products.ID).ToList();
}
```

Segue minha Entidade

```
public partial class Line
    {
        public Line()
        {
            this.Products = new List<Product>();
        }
        [Required]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DesktopImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string MobileImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string AltImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Position { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Erro acontece porque você não esta retornando uma lista de `Line`.
Tente isso:

```
public List<Line> Get()
{
    return context.
        Lines.
        Join(
            context.Products,
            lines => lines.ID,
            products => products.LineID,
            ((products, lines)
                => new { lines, products}
        ))
        .Select(s => s.lines)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.products.ID).ToList();
}
```

Mas, não faz sentido o uso de `Join`. Se voce não vai usar um `Where` para filtrar os dados, você esta simplismente juntando valores de 2 tabelas. Sendo que `Line` Ja possui uma lista de `products`.. Espero ter ajudado